# Differences in Halachic wording - "This isn't X" or "This is not Kosher X"

Tags: halacha-theory, mishna, sukkah, talmudic-methodology

In [Succah 8b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.8b.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) I noticed two different wordings regarding a Succah:

> א"ר לוי משום ר"מ שתי סוכות של יוצרים זו לפנים מזו -
>   הפנימית **אינה סוכה**
>   R' Levi said in the name of R' Meir: two craftsmen’s booths, one within the other, the inner one **is not a Succah**

And two lines down:

> תנו רבנן גנב"ך: סוכת גוים, סוכת נשים, סוכת בהמה, סוכת כותים, 
>   סוכה מכל מקום - **כשרה**
>   The Sages taught:.. a Succah of gentiles, a Succah of women, a Succah of domesticated animals, a Succah of Samaritans, a Succah of any sort, **is Kosher**

Literally, in the first case, a booth is *not called a Succah at all*, in the second *it is a Succah, but not Kosher*. This pattern seems common in other Halachic realms also and, according to the way of common interpretations, is used interchangeably.

However, I was told that we should put close attention to the Sages' wording and there's a reason for such a difference.

So is there a difference and, if yes, what does it mean?

Comment: +1 This isn’t unique to Sukkah; you find throughout Gittin a difference between אינו גט vs. גט פסול/גט בטל, and likewise in various sugyos a difference between אינו תנאי vs. תנאי בטל. In the Gittin cases it’s easier to differentiate based on context, but I’m not sure how to extend that to Sukkah.

Comment: In the 2nd case it *is* kosher

Comment: The Rambam's fantastic shorthand of "Get Batel" vs "Get Pasul" -- if it doesn't meet the biblical criteria it's "null and void"; if it doesn't meet some the rabbis' additional criteria it's "flawed." (Tremendous *nafka mina* on that -- we wouldn't call the new kids *mamzerim*, and would let her stay married to the new husband, just go get a Gett when/if you can.)

Comment: @Shalom Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Gemorah seems to go on to make the following distinction.

The first case is not a sukkah because it is not a temporary dwelling. The Gemora continues to say that therefore as a permanent structure it is obligated in a Mezuza

The second case is a sukkah (temporary dwelling) so therefore it *not* is obligated in a Mezuza.  The only question remaining is if it meets the criteria of a Kosher Sukka.

IOW It would be similar to saying:  An apple is not an Esrog. An Esrog that someone took a bite out of is not a Kosher Esrog

Comment: Interesting +1, 1. you're saying it's just to the opinion that Succah must be temporary - what would the other (R' Yehuda) that demand permanent dwelling, say? 2. How about one that only opens the roof of one's house and puts Schach - the house is permanent and it can be a Succah.

Comment: Rashi  on the Gemora explains that since he lives there all year in a permanent manner there is nothing making it into a Sukka, Once you take off  the roof you are clearly changing  the structure and making it into a Sukka

Comment: Why can’t you do the same with סוכת יוצרים? Just לפקפק את הסכך?